# Как правильно заполнить и загрузить Procfile ботa телеграм на Python на Heroku?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, heroku, бот

Почему после загрузки Procfile продолжает писать:
Warning: Your application is missing a Procfile. This file tells Heroku how to run your application.
?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так выглядит папка:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Содержимое Procfile:

web: python main.py

Почему так происходит? Как сделать всё правильно?

Comment: @D-side прошу меня простить, совсем не разбираюсь, а как это проверить? есть это то, что я думаю, то в командной строке git add Procfile выдает - fatal: pathspec 'Procfile' did not much any files

Comment: А, ха-ха-ха! Всё просто. У вас и правда нет Procfile. На скриншот посмотрите, ваш файл называется иначе. А Проводник немножко врёт. Можете вывести список файлов командой `dir` и убедиться.

Answer (score 1):

Procfile должен быть без расширения .txt
например, можно файл сохранять в блокноте, имя файла написать в кавычках "", тип - "Все файлы *.*".
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]